# Python 2.7: Multiprocessing: How to not block whilst using a queue for communication

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using a Queue for communicating between processes and also an event flag to indicate whether or not the parent process wants to exit however the Queue in child process is in a blocked state, waiting for more input.

I can make the queue not block by using get_nowait() however that is making the processor use 100%

What is the recommended way of being able to close a child process and accept input at the same time?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Event
from multiprocessing import Queue

class EchoProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, iQ, closeEvent):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.iQ = iQ
        self.closeEvent = closeEvent

    def run(self):
        while not self.closeEvent.is_set():
            istring = self.iQ.get()
            print(istring)
        print("exited")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iQ = Queue()
    closeEvent = Event()
    echoProcess = EchoProcess(iQ, closeEvent)
    echoProcess.start()
    while True:
        istring = raw_input("Enter:")
        if istring == "quit": break
        iQ.put(istring)
    closeEvent.set()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a sentinel.

Define the sentinel as a value that never appears in normal data and when EchoProcess gets it, it quits.

For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue

class Sentinel(object): pass

class EchoProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, iQ):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.iQ = iQ

    def run(self):
        for istring in iter(iQ.get, Sentinel):
            print(istring)
        print("exited")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iQ = Queue()
    echoProcess = EchoProcess(iQ)
    echoProcess.start()
    while True:
        istring = raw_input("Enter:")
        if istring == "quit": break
        iQ.put(istring)
    iQ.put(Sentinel)
    echoProcess.join()
```

Comment: I would like to avoid the sentinel approach if possible :) Using None seems does make sense.

Comment: OK, then do `iQ.get(timeout=0.1)`.

Comment: The caveat of adding a timeout is that it slows down the processing. It is okay for this example but in a larger example the speed slowdown is significant enough to matter. A timeout of 0.1 would result in the smallest amount of time the OS can deschedule a thread which maybe > 0.1 seconds

Comment: @Har why do you prefer to not use a sentinel? It's really the best option here.

Comment: Time timeout is only important for the exit case. It will not wait if it gets a message. It will not slow down processing.

Comment: My reservation is that it could be that a sentinel maybe a valid value so I would like to avoid it. I was hoping for a library feature in python could be us.

Comment: That is a valid concern though in practice, it has never been a problem for me. When you use threads, one object() can be used as sentinel without this problem.

Comment: @Har just create a custom Sentinel class, and send that. No risk of it being a valid value then. I guess you could make the child process a `daemon`, which would allow your main process to kill the child when it (the main process) is done, but that's potentially unsafe, depending on what the child process does. Your example above could use it, though.

Comment: yes thats a great idea :) of using a custom class as a sentinel

Comment: could you extend your example to include this javier?

Comment: Done but didn't test it. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: @Har another nice trick here; instad of using `while True: istring = self.iQ.get(); if istring == Sentinel: break`, you can just use `for istring in iter(self.iQ.get, Sentinel):`. `iter` continuously calls `self.iQ.get()` and assigns it to `istring`, but then breaks out of the loop when it hits `Sentinel`.